# How to Justify a Image Grid?

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I want all the rows to be of the same width and the images to occupy the full width of the row. Images can be fit to cover the dimensions. I have attached the code pen: https://codepen.io/shridhar_ke/pen/gOvpZOB

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 4px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.row img {
  margin-left: 8px;
  horizontal-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100.png" style="height:100%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x200.png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png" style="height:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x240.png" style="height:100%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png" style="height:100%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200.png" style="height:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x300.png" style="height:100%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x200.png" style="height:100%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x180.png" style="height:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the width of each image to be proportional to its natural width compared to the other two images in its row, regardless of their relative natural heights?

Comment: Yes...I just want all the rows to be of the same width and the images in the row should occupy full width. So the width should be proportional to the natural width and the height should be equal to the height of the row. The object-fit can be set to cover to crop the image to that ratio.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with pure CSS. You need a JS which stores all the image widths and sort them with an algoritm

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible with pure CSS. The key here is using the [flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

### Using the flex property

By setting `flex: 1 1 auto;` to the images, they're allowed to grow or shrink in order to fill up the entire row.

The only 'problem' here is that when the viewport gets too small, some rows will start shrinking and others won't. This is due to the fact that the height of your rows is hard coded to 150px. This is demonstrated by the code below:

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 4px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  /* Can be left out:
  text-align: justify; */
}

.row img {
  margin-left: 8px;
  /* This property doesn't exist:
  horizontal-align: middle; */
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Can be left out:
  width: auto; */
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* Added this property */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x200.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x240.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x300.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x200.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x180.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### Adding responsive units to the mix

This problem can be fixed by changing the height of the rows using a responsive unit, like vw (viewport width), like I did in the final version below:

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 4px;
  height: 15vw; /* Changed this property */
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.row img {
  margin-left: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* Added this property */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x200.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x240.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x300.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x200.png" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x180.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```